# Custom multiline textarea element

Tags: webforms

I need to render some text out of a bunch of node objects so that they are listed like this in the textarea field:

Item1
Price1: ---
Price2: ---
Item2
etc..

I created a custom element module for this, and mostly copied the example element in the webform module.

Element/WebformProductElement.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\webform_product_element\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

/**
 * Provides a 'webform_product_element'.
 *
 * Webform elements are just wrappers around form elements, therefore every
 * webform element must have correspond FormElement.
 *
 * Below is the definition for a custom 'webform_product_element' which just
 * renders a simple text field.
 *
 * @FormElement("webform_product_element")
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement
 * @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderElement
 * @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/namespace/Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element
 * @see \Drupal\webform_product_element\Element\WebformproductElement
 */
class WebformProductElement extends FormElement {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getInfo() {
    $class = get_class($this);
    return [
      '#input' => TRUE,
      '#size' => 220,
      '#process' => [
        [$class, 'processWebformElementproduct'],
        [$class, 'processAjaxForm'],
      ],
      '#element_validate' => [
        [$class, 'validateWebformproductElement'],
      ],
      '#pre_render' => [
        [$class, 'preRenderWebformproductElement'],
      ],
      '#theme' => 'input__webform_product_element',
      '#theme_wrappers' => ['form_element'],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Processes a 'webform_product_element' element.
   */
  public static function processWebformElementproduct(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    // Here you can add and manipulate your element's properties and callbacks.
    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * Webform element validation handler for #type 'webform_product_element'.
   */
  public static function validateWebformproductElement(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    // Here you can add custom validation logic.
  }

  /**
   * Prepares a #type 'email_multiple' render element for theme_element().
   *
   * @param array $element
   *   An associative array containing the properties of the element.
   *   Properties used: #title, #value, #description, #size, #maxlength,
   *   #placeholder, #required, #attributes.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The $element with prepared variables ready for theme_element().
   */
  public static function preRenderWebformproductElement(array $element) {
    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','product')->execute();
    $nodes =  Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    $text = "";
    foreach($nodes as $node){
      $text .= $node->get('field_name')->value . " - " . $node->get('field__per_bag')->value . " - " . $node->get('field_per_yard')->value . "/n";
    }
    $element['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
    $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'text_area';
    $element['#attributes']['value'] = $text;
    Element::setAttributes($element, ['id', 'name', 'value', 'size', 'maxlength', 'placeholder']);
    static::setAttributes($element, ['form-text', 'webform-product-element']);
    return $element;
  }

}
```

WebformElement/WebformProductElement.php:

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\webform_product_element\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

/**
 * Provides a 'webform_product_element'.
 *
 * Webform elements are just wrappers around form elements, therefore every
 * webform element must have correspond FormElement.
 *
 * Below is the definition for a custom 'webform_product_element' which just
 * renders a simple textarea.
 *
 * @FormElement("webform_product_element")
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement
 * @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderElement
 * @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/namespace/Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element
 * @see \Drupal\webform_product_element\Element\WebformproductElement
 */
class WebformProductElement extends FormElement {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getInfo() {
    $class = get_class($this);
    return [
      '#input' => TRUE,
      '#size' => 220,
      '#process' => [
        [$class, 'processWebformElementproduct'],
        [$class, 'processAjaxForm'],
      ],
      '#element_validate' => [
        [$class, 'validateWebformproductElement'],
      ],
      '#pre_render' => [
        [$class, 'preRenderWebformproductElement'],
      ],
      '#theme' => 'input__webform_product_element',
      '#theme_wrappers' => ['form_element'],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Processes a 'webform_product_element' element.
   */
  public static function processWebformElementproduct(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    // Here you can add and manipulate your element's properties and callbacks.
    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * Webform element validation handler for #type 'webform_product_element'.
   */
  public static function validateWebformproductElement(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    // Here you can add custom validation logic.
  }

  /**
   * Prepares a #type 'email_multiple' render element for theme_element().
   *
   * @param array $element
   *   An associative array containing the properties of the element.
   *   Properties used: #title, #value, #description, #size, #maxlength,
   *   #placeholder, #required, #attributes.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The $element with prepared variables ready for theme_element().
   */
  public static function preRenderWebformproductElement(array $element) {
    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','product')->execute();
    $nodes =  Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    $text = "";
    foreach($nodes as $node){
      $text .= $node->get('field_name')->value . " - " . $node->get('field__per_bag')->value . " - " . $node->get('field_per_yard')->value . "\n";
    }
    $element['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
    $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'textarea';
    $element['#attributes']['value'] = $text;
    Element::setAttributes($element, ['id', 'name', 'value', 'size', 'maxlength', 'placeholder']);
    static::setAttributes($element, ['form-text', 'webform-product-element']);
    return $element;
  }

}
```

But when I go to add my new element to my webform it looks like this:
[image]

I need this to be a multiline text field, so that each nodes info is properly spaced out.

Comment: This `$element['#attributes']['type'] = 'textarea';` likely needs to be this `$element['type'] = 'textarea';`

Comment: That gives me this: "User error: "type" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 98 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php)
"

Comment: Well, textarea is not a valid HTML attribute value for type, so the line of code you have will also be incorrect, regardless of mine not working. It's been a few years since I created a new Form API element, but IIRC they require a template. What does your template look like for this element? For example, I had to do this template for the jQuery Colorpicker element: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/jquery_colorpicker/-/blob/8.x-2.x/templates/jquery-colorpicker.html.twig